# Integral with$\frac{ x^2}{a^2} +\frac{y^2}{b^2} +\frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$

Tags: calculus

I have a question.

I need to compute the integral
$$\iiint\limits_\Delta \left(\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2}\right) dx\,dy\,dz
$$
over the domain $\Delta$ defined by $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 = 1$.

And I need to use the transformation $x=au$, $y=bv$, $z=cw$. Can somebody help me? I don't know either how I can find the bounds.

Comment: Advice about typing: $$\int\int\int \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} dxdydz$$ over the domain  $$D: \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$.

Answer (score 2):

If you use $x = au$, $y = bv$ and $z = cw$ then the determinant of the [Jacobbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) is

$$
\left|\frac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (u,v,w)}\right| = abc
$$

So that

$$
\iiint {\rm d}x{\rm d}y{\rm d}z \left(\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2}\right) = \iiint {\rm d}x{\rm d}y{\rm d}z~ abc(u^2 + v^2 + w^2)
$$
You can go a step further and call

$$
u = r\sin\theta \cos\phi, ~~~ v = r\sin\theta\sin\phi, ~~~ w = r\cos\theta
$$

with $r \le 1$, $0\le \theta \le \pi$ and $0 \le \phi < 2\pi$. The Jacobbian now has determinant $r^2\sin\theta$ and then

\begin{eqnarray}
\iiint {\rm d}x{\rm d}y{\rm d}z \left(\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2}\right) &=& \iiint {\rm d}x{\rm d}y{\rm d}z~ abc(u^2 + v^2 + w^2) \\
&=& abc\int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\phi\int_0^\pi{\rm d}\theta \int_0^1{\rm d}r~ r^4\sin\theta
\end{eqnarray}

And you can take it from here

Comment: note that the domain is only the surface of the sphere, so $r=1$

Comment: Also, in the integral, when you change $x=au$, then $dx=adu$